# Copying Outlook folder structure to Windows explorer

Tags: vba, directory, outlook, subdirectory

This is my code for this task. The issue is with the invalid characters in Windows. I can replace them fine on files but on folders in doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim xFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Sub CopyOutlookFldStructureToWinExplorer()
    ExportAction "Copy"
End Sub

Sub ExportAction(xAction As String)
Dim xFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim xFldPath As String
xFldPath = SelectAFolder()
If xFldPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "You did not select a folder. Export cancelled.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Kutools for Outlook"
Else
    Set xFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set xFolder = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    ExportOutlookFolder xFolder, xFldPath
End If
Set xFolder = Nothing
Set xFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ExportOutlookFolder(ByVal OutlookFolder As Outlook.Folder, xFldPath As String)
Dim xSubFld As Outlook.Folder
Dim xItem As Object
Dim xPath As String
Dim xFilePath As String
Dim xSubject As String
Dim xFilename As String
On Error Resume Next
xPath = xFldPath & "\" & OutlookFolder.Name
'?????????,??????
If Dir(xPath, 16) = Empty Then MkDir xPath
For Each xItem In OutlookFolder.Items
    xItem = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(xItem.Item)
    xSubject = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(xItem.Subject)
    xSubFld = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(xItem.SubFld)
    xFldPath = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(xItem.FldPath)
    xPath = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(xItem.Path)
    xSubject = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(xItem.Subject)
    xFilename = xSubject & ".msg"
    xFilename = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(xItem.FileName)
    xFilePath = xPath & "\" & xFilename
    xFilePath = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(xItem.FilePath)
    If xFSO.FileExists(xFilePath) Then
        xCounter = xCounter + 1
        xFilename = xSubject & " (" & xCounter & ").msg"
        xFilePath = xPath & "\" & xFilename
        xFilePath = ReplaceInvalidCharacters(xItem.FilePath)
    End If
    xItem.SaveAs xFilePath, olMSG
Next
For Each xSubFld In OutlookFolder.Folders
    ExportOutlookFolder xSubFld, xPath
Next
Set OutlookFolder = Nothing
Set xItem = Nothing
End Sub

Function SelectAFolder() As String
Dim xSelFolder As Object
Dim xShell As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set xShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set xSelFolder = xShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a folder", 0, 0)
If Not TypeName(xSelFolder) = "Nothing" Then
    SelectAFolder = xSelFolder.self.Path
End If
Set xSelFolder = Nothing
Set xShell = Nothing
End Function

Function ReplaceInvalidCharacters(Str As String) As String
Dim xRegEx
Set xRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
xRegEx.Global = True
xRegEx.IgnoreCase = False
xRegEx.Pattern = "\||\/|\<|\>|""|:|\*|\\|\?"
ReplaceInvalidCharacters = xRegEx.Replace(Str, "_")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Always use `Option Explicit` at the very top of every module, before any function. This will tell you if you have not `Dim`'med any variables. In this case there is an issue with `xCount` and `xCounter`, which should have only one name.
2. I think the problem may come from the function `ExportOutlookFolder`, this line:
   `xPath = xFldPath & "\" & OutlookFolder.Name`
   Try replacing it with:
   `xPath = xFldPath & "\" & ReplaceInvalidCharacters(OutlookFolder.Name)`